# Looking for replacement or datasheet of this component

Tags: diodes, identification, replacement

I have a burned diode. (I fortunately found an exact same component in the circuit elsewhere to take a photo.) It says `132Y` or `B2Y`

Could you please give me a hint what can I use as replacement?

[image]

Comment: Could also be "i32y" however I don't think it is "B2Y".

Comment: From your measurements, it is a Schottky diode. But before making any replacements, it would be wise to determine the root cause of failure. It might be challenging.

Comment: @Ali Chen Yes, after I removed the burned diode, the ends of the pcb traces are still shorted somewhere else. I will have fun to find out what else is died... BTW the root cause could be trivial, the unit has a reverse polarised DC plug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found it by searching in google images.
I think it's a **MBR0520L** Schottky diode.

The marking is **B2** (not 132) and the Y at the end is maybe some date code, not part of the ID.

I've found two similar ones:
https://www.yoycart.com/Product/41957191681/
[image: B2 diode]

https://www2.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/MBR0520L?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv%252bkWzvOmGqmnBRc%252btURriS
[image: B2Y diode]

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

The "132Y" is just a short product code.  There is no direct way to get from product codes to real part numbers, or even to find the manufacturer.  If you know the manufacturer and part family, you can look in the datasheet to see which variant has the specific product code.  But without knowing anything else, going from product code to part number is way too tedius to bother with.

It's hard to say from your picture, but that might be a SMA package.  Diodes in SMA packages are usually good for around 1 A.  The reverse voltage could be anything, and so could other characteristics like reverse recovery time.

The best bet is to find or trace the circuit.  Show us the schematic, and we may be able to infer the specs.  From that, you can find a suitable replacement.

Comment: Also, this is diode D47. Meaning there's at least 46 other diodes in that circuit. Carefully unsolder one of them with the same marking, if you can find one, and measure it!

Comment: There is only one exactly like the burned one. I've unsoldered it. It has 0.2V-0.159V opening voltage (depends on which multimeter is used), and it is always open from the other direction, so it's not a Zener. I try to do some circuit tracing later.

Comment: if it's burned, what you measure is irrelevant, sadly.

Comment: I mean I have two diodes in the circuit. a burned one, and a good one. The measurements and the picture above are from the good one.